# Position absolute and horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a few svg blobs I need to add to the background. One of them should overflow the view port i.e. only part of the blob is visible and most of it is hidden beyond the view port. I did that with `position: absolute;` but that caused horizontal scrolling. I've looked for solutions but the one solution I keep seeing didn't work for me. People have recommended to wrap the image and add `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper. But that makes the image disappear completely, not just the overflow part.

Is there a way to position a background image so that it overflows the view port but doesn't cause horizontal scrolling? Replacing `position: absolute` with `position: fixed` sort of does the trick, the horizontal scrolling is gone but due to the nature of the property, the blob is just staying there while you scroll the page down. That's not the behavior I need. Here's the code I've got so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="blob">
<img src="https://81766.com/wp-content/uploads/blob-shape01.svg?x48940" class="blob-img">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.blob {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.blob-img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  right: -220px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code to so its a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a height to the blob class (>= 400px).

Setting position to absolute decouples the layout flow from its ancestor/parent.  This means that its dimensions do not determine the dimensions of the parent.  Because there is no other element inside the the blob div, its height is still 0. If you add another element with some height (and not 'position'ed) it will also show up the image.  (Not 100% sure yet why the calculated height of the SVG does not do this (could be because part of the image is hidden so the browser thinks its height is 0), but forcing a height, either explicitly or implicitly, on the blob div fixes the problem.)

Just to be clear, the working code:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.blob {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 400px;
}

.blob-img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  right: -220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blob">
<img src="https://81766.com/wp-content/uploads/blob-shape01.svg?x48940" class="blob-img">
  </div>
```